# how to make image slider resize according to window

Tags: html, css, animation

I have an animated slideshow using CSS.I can't figure out how to make the slider resize according to the window size,currently it stays the same size no matter what the browser screen size is.

Here is the slider code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slider {     
 ...
 div#slidercontainer { 
position: relative;

border-left:150px solid white; 

overflow: hidden; 
background: #000 
}
div#slidercontainer { 
width: 900px;
height: 400px; 
}

div#sider img {  
width: 900px;
height: 400px; 
float: left;
 }

div#css3slider { 
position: absolute; 
width:4500px;  
...}



div#css3slider img { 
float: right; 
 }
<div id=slidercontainer>
 <div id=css3slider style="width:fill,margin-left:200px">
<img src=ban1.jpg alt="Square-tailed kite">
<img src=ban2.jpg alt="White-tailed kite">
<img src=ban3.jpg alt=Hawk title=Hawk>
<img src=ban4.jpg alt=Osprey>
<img src=ban1.jpg alt="Square-tailed kite">
</div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how i should fix it to respond to screen size?

Answer (score 0):

Well by the looks of your css code you have given fixed width, in responsive the widths should not be fixed, but it should be set in percentage, only then will the images resize according to browser window.

First of all set the main container width in percentage, according to what you need and you should also set the images to percentage as well. Images width can be set to 100%, by setting it to 100% this means they are 100% of the parents width.

So, whatever the width of the parent div is in percentage, the width of images always be 100% of that.

Also I am not sure, but I think that you might have to add an extra line in js as well, the make the slider responsive

Comment: I did figure it out, it was possible with JS, in the code in question fixed width was needed because it was holding images of that width and image width is not dynamic si didn't seem possible without JS.
Cheers :)